# gcc linker options "--format binary"?

Tags: gcc, linker

What is the meaning/usage of '--format binary' options in below command ?.

```
ld -m elf_x86_64  --format binary  --oformat elf64-x86-64 -r stub -o stub-image.o
```

Answer (score 3):

The `-format binary` option states that the input file, in this case named `stub`, is a raw binary blob of data.

The command you show takes this 'blob' and wraps it up in an *elf* file, similar to other objects created by the compiler, and suitable for linking into a program. This sort of trick is also useful if you have a ROM-programming tool, for example, that expects elf data rather than raw binaries.

The blob is placed in the `.data` section, and three symbols (a.k.a. variables) are created for you:

- `_binary_stub_start`
- `_binary_stub_end`
- `_binary_stub_size`

If you link `stub-image.o` with a C program, in the usual way, then you can access the data like this (you can choose whatever pointer type is appropriate):

```
extern char *binary_stub_start;
```